# Mips finding structural hazard data hazard in mips code

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

```
(i1)  lw $1,40($2) 
(i2) add $2,$3,$3 
(i3) add $1,$1,$2 
(i4) sw $1,20($2)
```

Given that forwarding is not supported i’ve found there will be data hazard in $2(on line i2 i3)
Are there any hazards in this mips code?

And if forwarding is supported ,are there still any hazards?

Comment: Without forwarding, i1 -> i3 might be a problem for the load result.  That's as early as the load is available *with* forwarding, so IIRC it wouldn't be without forwarding.  And i2 -> i4 for the `$2` is probably also a problem, even if i3->14 didn't already make it stall even longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's state that this question applies to a pipelined processor, rather than a single cycle processor.

Second, let's assume that `WB` (write back) executes instantly at the beginning of the cycle — this is realistic b/c `WB` doesn't have to compute anything and the value for it to store into the register file is available at the very beginning of the cycle.

And that then the `ID` from a later instruction can capture the value written by `WB` from an earlier instruction, via overlap in the same cycle.

```
cycle-> 1   2   3   4   5
  (i1) IF  ID  EX  MEM WB
  (i2)     IF  ID  EX  MEM WB
  (i3)         IF  ID  EX  MEM WB
  (i4)             IF  ID  EX  MEM WB
  (i5)                 IF  ID  EX  MEM WB
```

In cycle 5, when (i1) does `WB`, (i4) can read the proper value in `ID` as they are overlapping — and as per the above this is sufficient for (i4) to read values written by (i1).

However, neither (i2) nor (i3) can see values written by (i1) because their `ID` stage, which reads values, occurs before (i1)'s `WB` stage.  *(i2)'s `ID` stage is in cycle 3 and (i3)'s `ID` stage is in cycle 4 whereas (i1)'s `WB` stage is in cycle 5.*

(*If the overlapping read/write in the same cycle did not work, then per the above diagram, only (i5) in `ID` would see the result of (i1)'s `WB`.*)

So, we can extend this diagram (or apply it to each instruction in a sequence as if i1) to see how many hazards there are in your example.

---

This means that in your sequence, (i1)'s `WB` of `$1` is not available for any `ID` to read until (i4), and then that (i3) would require a forward/bypass (MEM->EX) to obtain the proper value.

For (i3) to obtain (i2)'s update to `$2`, a forward/bypass (EX->EX) is necessary.

For (i4) to obtain (i2)'s update to `$2`, a forward/bypass (MEM->EX) is necessary.

For (i4) to obtain (i3)'s update to `$1`, a forward/bypass (EX->EX) is necessary.

---

There is a case (not shown in your example) where both a forward/bypass (MEM->EX) and a stall is necessary, this happens when the very next instruction sources the value targeted by an immediately prior load instruction, since the proper value for load is only available from MEM (whereas for computational instructions, the proper value is available from EX).

Comment: Another way to say "WB executes instantly" is that the register file is written in the first half-cycle, and read by ID in the 2nd half-cycle, so it can see values written by WB in the same cycle.  Because that's normally true in practice.  (Perhaps without the actual half-cycle read/write separation, if it's multi-ported and writes in the same cycle do lead to the read result stabilizing on the just-written value.)

Comment: Classic MIPS I (R2000) didn't have an interlock for loads; it only stalled on cache miss.  If you tried to use the load result in the next instruction, you'd get the old register value (or on cache miss, the load result, so it wasn't something you could predictable "take advantage of" like on The Mill).  It was only later generations (MIPS II) that introduced the ability to stall+forward as you describe, removing the "load delay slot" as a correctness issue, only performance.  (i.e. saving I-cache footprint when the compiler couldn't find anything to fill a load delay slot with.)